# Is keras exclusive to binary output only? When I set my y output to non binary my accuracy becomes zero, keras, tensorlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I set y to binary values [0,1] I have a high accuracy, however when I set it to non-binary [1,2,3] values I get 0 accuracy. Is Keras exclusive to binary only?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
from numpy import loadtxt
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)

numpy.random.seed(7)

dataset = loadtxt('Trial.csv', delimiter=',')
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
# split into input (X) and output (y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:2]
Data_1 = X.astype('float32')
y = dataset[:,3]
Data_2 = y.astype("float32")
# define the keras model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(Data_1, Data_2, epochs=15, batch_size=100)
# evaluate the keras model
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(Data_1, Data_2)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
```

Comment: `activation='sigmoid'` outputs real values in range `[0, 1]`, so it'll never output 2 or 3

Comment: The output function needs to be softmax and you need as many neurons as label. I suggest you understand better how neural network works before doing the coding. Mostly architecture and activation functions.

Answer (score 1):

It's because final layer of your model is classifying the dataset into Binary output, which is correct for classification of 2 classes.

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))  # Here it's assuming Binary output
```

If you change the `final dense layer` units to other than 1 (or as per number of classes) and activation function as `'Softmax'`, you will have different output range for multi-class classification.

```
model.add(Dense(num_of_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

Also change the activation function to `'relu'` for other Dense layers.

```
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
```

For better understanding, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70218690/mode-predict-is-returing-a-list-just-with-mainly-1s/70361672#70361672) similar issue.