# mode.predict() is returing a list just with mainly 1's

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I just recently trained a model with 10 labels. It has trained properly, but when I run model.predict() on my test data, It returns a list full of 1's, with some number <1 occasionally. Like-

(Code)-

```
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=((size**2)*3,), activation='sigmoid')])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train_array, y_train, epochs=100)

y_predict_test=model.predict(X_test_array)

print(y_predict_test)
```

Output-

```
[[1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00
  1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00]
 [1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00
  1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 9.4951046e-01 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00]
 [1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00
  8.6665523e-01 1.0000000e+00 9.9999869e-01 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00]
 [1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00
  1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00]
 [1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00
  1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 5.0568581e-03 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00]
 [1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00
  1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00]...
```

And this results in argmax returning just 0's as the label. How do I fix this? Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Try adding more layers.

Comment: Oh. How many should I add? And which activation function should I use?

Comment: Add 3 or 4 layers, with 32 or 64 units, with `relu` activation function, and `softmax` activation in the output layer.

Answer (score 1):

This above output type is caused by using `'sigmoid'` activation function.

**Sigmoid** - `Sigmoid` is equivalent to a 2-element Softmax, where the second element is assumed to be zero. The sigmoid function always returns a value between 0 and 1. Hence mostly used in `Binary Classification`.

**Softmax** - Whereas `Softmax` activation function used for multi-class predictions. The output could be interpreted as a probability distribution. The sum of all outputs generated by softmax is 1.

As it is `multi-class classification` problem. So, changing the activation function from `sigmoid` to `softmax` will change the output into desired format:

```
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=((size**2)*3,), activation='softmax')])
```

Further, you can examine the test label shows that this classification is correct or not:

```
import numpy as np
print(y_test[1])  # actual label
np.argmax(y_predict_test[1]) # predicted label
```